# Create list with fixed-size and null values and then modify him Kotlin

Tags: list, kotlin

I have a class

```
data class A(
        var id: Long? = null,
        var desc: String,
        var cnt: String
)
```

I want to create a list with 5 elements of the type of this class A, where all the elements are unique and using a functional programming style. For example,

```
[A(id=1, desc="t1", cnt="s1"), A(id=2, desc="t2", cnt="s2"), A(id=3, desc="t3", cnt="s3"), A(id=4, desc="t4", cnt="s4"), A(id=5, desc="t5", cnt="s5")]
```

I tried to do it like this, but it seems to me there is a more ideal way (if i want 100 size...)

```
        val aList = mutableOf<A>(null, null, null, null, null)
        aList.forEachIndexed { index, _ ->
            x = createA() // here an entity is created and a unique id is assigned
            alist[index] = A(
                    id = x.id,
                    desc = x.desc+index,
                    cnt= x.cnt+index
            )
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating a mutable list and using [`forEachIndexed`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/for-each-indexed.html),
you can use a [constructor-like function for lists](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/constructing-collections.html#initializer-functions-for-lists) ([Source Code](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/collections/Collections.kt#L138-L149)) with a lambda.

Additionally, consider using string templates rather than concatenation:

```
data class A(
    var id: Long? = null,
    var desc: String,
    var cnt: String
)

fun main() {
    val aList = List(5) { index ->
        A(
            id = (index + 1).toLong(),
            desc = "t${index + 1}",
            cnt = "s${index + 1}"
        )
    }
    println(aList)
}
```

**Output:**

```
[A(id=1, desc=t1, cnt=s1), A(id=2, desc=t2, cnt=s2), A(id=3, desc=t3, cnt=s3), A(id=4, desc=t4, cnt=s4), A(id=5, desc=t5, cnt=s5)]
```

Try it [**here!**](https://pl.kotl.in/HMVq-Woaw)

Comment: It's not called String "interpolation". It's called String "templates". The word *interpolation* means something completely different.

Comment: Today I Learned.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`List`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list.html) factory function to make a list of a desired size, and specify with a lambda what each index's element should be:

```
val aList = List(5) { index ->
    val x = createA()
    A(
        id = x.id,
        desc = x.desc + index,
        cnt = x.cnt + index
    )
    // or use the copy method on data classes:
    // x.copy(desc = x.desc + index, cnt = x.cnt + index)
}
```

That said, it seems a bit wasteful to create an `A`, just to create another `A` with some different properties. Consider making `createA` take an `Int` parameter, if you can change it of course.

```
val aList = List(5) { index ->
    createA(index)
}
// or written with a function reference
val aList = List(5, ::createA)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a range with *n..m* ([Ranges](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/ranges.html#range)) and then use [map](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kotlin-tour-collections.html#map) to create the entries:

```
val result = (1..5).map { A(id = it.toLong(), desc = "t$it", cnt = "s$it") }
```

Or if the value of the count of elements is stored in a variable:

```
val count = 5
val list = (1..count).map { ...
```

Note that the syntax of *n..m* creates an IntRange. For a LongRange there is no short syntax, one just uses the constructor, but on the otherside the *.toLong()* conversion could be dropped:

```
val list = LongRange(1, 5).map { A(id = it, desc = "t$it", cnt = "s$it") }
```